# What is the Jacobian for Sim(3) lie group action on 3D points ? (4d homogenous points)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am coding up Sim(3) constraint types for a factor graph, and need to calculate the jacobian of the Sim(3) group action on 3D points.

I am following the guide on http://ethaneade.com/lie.pdf although it does not calculate it for Sim(3).

My generators for the lie algebra associated with Sim(3) are stored as a 7D vector in the order $(t_1,t_2,t_3,R_1,R_2,R_3,s)$.

The matrix representation of a Sim(3) group element in the library I am using (Sophus) stores it as a 4 × 4 matrix $\begin{pmatrix}s R && t \\ 0 && 1\end{pmatrix}$. Thus, the group action on a 4D homogeneous point would be

$$y = sRx + t$$

This derivative wrt $x$ would be $dy/dx = sR$.

Derivative wrt $R$ would be (as calculated for SE(3) in the reference above) = $-[y]_x$
(I hope this is correct!)

Derivative wrt the translation vector would be = Identity(3,3)

I want to calculate the derivative wrt scale '$s$'. 
Would it be equal to $R x = (1/s)(y - t)$ ?

Then would the jacobian be a 3 × 7 matrix with columns stacked as $[I_3 -[y]_x (1/s)(y - t)]$ ??

I am not really a math major and this is my first face-off with lie groups.

Thanks.

PS: [This paper](http://roboticsproceedings.org/rss06/p10.pdf) briefly mentions what I am doing. Check from eq(21).

Answer (score 3):

I searched this question online and got no exact answer, and finally figured sim(3) jacobian out by combine some references, and codes. I summarised and write code for sim(3) optimize at repository below.

[CeresSim3Optimize](https://github.com/b51/CeresSim3Optimize), the README is coded in latex format, can be displayed with chrome extension [Tex all the things](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tex-all-the-things/cbimabofgmfdkicghcadidpemeenbffn).